# Flink: understanding the dataflow of my program

Tags: apache-flink

I've develop a Flink program that reads tweets from Twitter and push them on Kafka. Then it get back the tweets from Kafka and process them.

The "Tweets processing" transformation extracts hashtags and users from the text of the tweet and emit them in the default output and every pair of them in a side output.

The attached image is picked from the Flink Web UI. I don't understand why the Kafka Source and the Tweets processing operator are merged into a single task and primarily I want that the Tweets sink receive all the raw tweets from the Kafka Source not the output of the Tweets processing operator.

Is the program correct?

[Datalow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCEcS.png)

This the relevant part of the code:

```
    FlinkKafkaConsumer010<String> myConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<String>(Constants.KAFKA_TWEETS_TOPIC, new SimpleStringSchema(), properties);
    myConsumer.setStartFromLatest();

    DataStream<String> tweetsStream = env
            .addSource(myConsumer)
            .name("Kafka tweets consumer");

    SingleOutputStreamOperator<List<String>> tweetsAggregator = tweetsStream
            .timeWindowAll(Time.seconds(7))
            .aggregate(new StringAggregatorFunction())
            .name("Tweets aggregation");

    DataStreamSink tweetsSink = tweetsAggregator.addSink(new TweetsSink())
            .name("Tweets sink")
            .setParallelism(1);

    SingleOutputStreamOperator<String> termsStream = tweetsStream
            // extracting terms from tweets
            .process(new TweetParse())
            .name("Tweets processing");

    DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> counts = termsStream
            .map(new ToTuple())
            // Counting terms
            .keyBy(0)
            .timeWindow(Time.seconds(13))
            .sum(1)
            .name("Terms processing");

    DataStream<Tuple3<String, String, Integer>> edgesStream = termsStream.getSideOutput(TweetParse.outputTag)
            .map(new ToTuple3())
            // Counting terms pairs
            .keyBy(0, 1)
            .timeWindow(Time.seconds(19))
            .sum(2)
            .name("Edges processing");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two different dataflow with `tweetsStream`. the first is `tweetsAggregator` and the second is `termsStream`. Then you are creating two different dataflow from termsStream again: `counts` and `edgesStream`. The Sink operators has no output. So it cannot generate data to another operator and it must be the last operator to use. You have to start with a data Source operator `addSource(myConsumer)`, chain as much as transformation you want `timeWindowAll`, `aggregate`, `map`, `keyBy`, and then call a sink operator. You can call more than one sink if you want, but remember that sinks don't generate data stream to other operators, they are consumers.